# How to validate schema of list of dicts in python?

Tags: python, validation, schema, jsonschema

I have a dictionary with config info:

```
“request”:
    {
        “request_id”: uuid,
        "points": {
            "<point_id>": {"weight": float},
        }
    }
```

For example

```
"request":{
     "request_id": "553380e1-fa37-4666-886e-7f56c0540ed8",
     "points": {
          "0": {
             "weight": 5
          },
          "1": {
             "weight":10
          }
     }
}
```

It should be like this?

```
"request": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "request_id": {
            "type": "string",
        },
        "points":{
             "type": "array",
             "items": {
                ????
             }
        }
    }
```

I am not able to find the validation schema in my flask project. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: [Marshmallow](https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) provides schema validation functionality to flask apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`points` is an object, not an integer. You can specify variable property names with a regular expression in `patternProperties`, or if the property names can be anything, use `additionalProperties` to constrain the values.

```json
...
"points": {
  "patternProperties": {
    "^[0-9]+$": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "weight": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```